# array.sty is missing in MikTex Console package database

Tags: packages, miktex, installing, arrays

I compiled a LaTex document using Texmaker and got the following error message
! LaTeX Error: File `array.sty' not found.

Normally, this error will be resolved after installing the package in the MikTeX console. However, I could not find package array in the MikTeX package list and, thus, could not install it.

I would appreciate if you can help me. Thanks

Comment: `array.sty` lives in the MikTeX package `latex-tools`. That package was only recently renamed to `latex-tools` (from I believe `tools`). This renaming may be an issue for the auto-installer. Update MikTeX and run "Tasks > Update package database" in Admin and User mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

install or update the `latex-tools` package, it worked for me.

Comment: How is this not an answer to the question?

Comment: This package is part of any MikTeX bundle. You only need to consider @moewe comment.