# Adding multicol package

Tags: multicol

When I run a latex file (TeXworks) and try to use this package (\usepackage{makeidx}) I get the following error

! LaTeX Error: File `multicol.sty' not found.

How can I resolve this?
Thanks

Comment: install the missing package with the package manager of your texsystem.

Comment: multicol is part of the required tools bundle so should be included in _every_ tex distribution.

Comment: This is I guess a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/578771/array-sty-is-missing-in-miktex-console-package-database  as it is also in `latex-tools`