# MikTeX: after recent upgrade where are documentation for packages array, longtable, hhline, tabularx ...?

Tags: miktex

It seems that after recent upgrade MikTeX move documentations of many standard packages for tables to some new folder with yet unknown name. Do anyone know name of this folder or how to find them?

Comment: see comment here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/578771/array-sty-is-missing-in-miktex-console-package-database

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It might make sense to post a regular answer such that it is easier to find ...

Comment: @gernot sure but not me I have never used miktex so I can't check any of the comments are right or even that the same fix fixes all these questions.

Comment: Zarko: maybe you want to self-answer? I don't have MiKTeX either ...

Comment: I will write it, ASAP. Firs I like to create my shortcuts to documentation in this folders.

Comment: It has gone to the `latex-tools`  subdirectory of `doc\latex`.

Comment: Doesn't MiKTeX have its own `texdoc` command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the recent upgrade of the MikTeX bundle to version 20.12 was changed name of folder `tools` where were collected packages among others for tables styles (`array`,`dcolumn`, `hhline`, `longtable`, `tabularx`)   to `latex-tools`. Folder for styles is in `.../MikTeX/tex/latex` and for its documentation in `.../MikTeX/doc/latex`.

Note: folders `tools` still exist, bit they are empty.

Thank you very much to all, who helped me to find this changes.

Comment: I had to install latex-tools as a package before the folder showed up.

Comment: note this mirrors the changing of the names at ctan and texlive to latex-base, latex-tools, latex-graphics from base,tools,graphics  that happened several years ago.

Comment: This solved my trouble. The auto-install didn't seem to pick up this change after updating MikTeX on windows 10. I got errors that the `tabularx.sty` wasn't found on my system for an article I had built before. Anyway, nothing is perfect.