# what does calc.sty missing from the foler mean

Tags: packages, calculations

This error suddenly appeared in my file! It was not before
what should I do?

File `calc.sty' not found. \RequirePackage

Comment: The `calc` package is part of _required_ tools bindle so should be available in every latex installation. If you are using miktex then update `latex-tools` in the miktex console

Comment: If you are using miktex this is most likely a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/578956/miktex-after-recent-upgrade-where-are-documentation-for-packages-array-longtab/578988#578988

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert but I try this and worked.

Copy all in this link: https://web.mit.edu/ghudson/dev/nokrb/third/tetex/texmf/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty

Paste in a note block and save as *calc.sty* where is save your .tex file

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  This would solve OP's problem, but wouldn't really address the underlying issue that TeX isn't finding a package that should be somewhere on OP's computer.