# TexWorks giving error "Unfortunately, the package tools could not be installed."

Tags: miktex

The above error is followed by the error mentioned below. I am getting this error while trying to compile the master's thesis present here.[Link to Masters Thesis template](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis) I have installed MikTex.

```
LaTeX Error: File `longtable.sty' not found.
```

Comment: if longtable sty is not found something is seriously broken with your tex system. But you are giving no details how you installed tex so it is quite difficult to help you. Are you using miktex or texlive?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have Miktex. Should I uninstall Texworks and MiKTeX and try again?

Comment: Sorry I can't say what you should do as I have no idea what it is wrong. But I would at first open the miktex console and check for updates (in admin and user mode), and try to install some packages.

Comment: have you not updated for some years? the tools bundle at texlive and ctan is called latex-tools now not tools I assume miktex is the same (@UlrikeFischer might confirm)

Comment: probably a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/578771/array-sty-is-missing-in-miktex-console-package-database

Comment: Is `longtable` package installed properly according to your MikTeX console?

Comment: @M.A.Bromuela the file longpackage belongs to the tools package I tried installing tools. Did not work. For the time being, I have mitigated the problem by not using longtables.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I updates miktex and texworks today. Reinstalled them both did not work.

Comment: Same problem here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that `longtable` has been put into a more global toolbox called `latex-tools`. Maybe you should try to just erase `\usepackage{longtable}` and compile your script again.